# Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, notices

This is an error I'm receiving when my plugin is activated:

> Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks.  Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /directory/ on line 3547

This is line 3547:

```
trigger_error( sprintf( __( '%1$s was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. %2$s %3$s' ), $function, $message, $version ) );
```

Here is the rest of the if statement for the WP_DEBUG output:

```
if ( WP_DEBUG && apply_filters( 'doing_it_wrong_trigger_error', true ) ) {
    if ( function_exists( '__' ) ) {
        $version = is_null( $version ) ? '' : sprintf( __( '(This message was added in version %s.)' ), $version );
        $message .= ' ' . __( 'Please see <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information.' );
        trigger_error( sprintf( __( '%1$s was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. %2$s %3$s' ), $function, $message, $version ) );
    } else {
        $version = is_null( $version ) ? '' : sprintf( '(This message was added in version %s.)', $version );
        $message .= ' Please see <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information.';
        trigger_error( sprintf( '%1$s was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. %2$s %3$s', $function, $message, $version ) );
    }
}
```

This is the only instance of wp_enqueue script I have in my plugin:

```
wp_enqueue_script('csv3', plugins_url( '/js/demo.js' , __FILE__ ) , array( 'jquery' ));
```

It's pretty much verbatim from [an example I found](http://www.inkthemes.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-for-data-insertion/) that performed the task I need

Here are the three functions that pass variables to the demo.js file:

```
function check_db(){
    global $table;
    global $quanid;
    $hf_userid = get_current_user_id();
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT count( 1 ) FROM $table WHERE ItemID = '$quanid' AND user = '$hf_userid'", ARRAY_A));
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_check_db', 'check_db');
    function update_entry(){
    global $quanid;
    $price = isset($_POST[$quanid]);
    $hf_userid = get_current_user_id();
    global $table;
    global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->prepare( '$table',
        array(
            'ItemID' => '$quanid',
            'Price' => $price,
            'user' => $hf_userid)));
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_update_entry', 'update_entry');
    function post_entry(){
    global $quanid;
    $price = isset($_POST[$quanid]);
    $hf_userid = get_current_user_id();
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prepare( 
        '$table', 
        array( 
            'ItemID' => '$quanid',
            'Price'  => $price,
            'user'   => $hf_userid
        ), 
        array( 
            '%d', '%d', '%d'
        ) 
    ));
    die();
    return true;
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_post_entry', 'post_entry');
```

Comment: Can you indent your code appropriatley and post the code that calls `wp_enqueue_script` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not show how you hook your `wp_enqueue_script()` call.

But the error message you get is pretty clear, use one of the following hooks:

- `wp_enqueue_scripts`
- `admin_enqueue_scripts`
- `login_enqueue_scripts`

depending on the use case - see the [notes at the `wp_enqueue_script()` codex page for additional information](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Notes).

For example do for correctly enqueuing on the frontend:

```
function csv_three_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'csv3', 
        plugins_url( 
            '/js/demo.js', 
            __FILE__ 
        ), 
        array( 
            'jquery'
        )
     );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'csv_three_script' );
```